# I can't show data in recyclerview for type mismatch

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-recyclerview, retrofit2

In my app I am successfully retrieving data from the server, I check data using logcat, it's fine, it's coming from the server. But I can't show this data in recyclerview because of Type mismatch issue. I am using retrofit in the MVVM pattern.

for better understanding, see the code below

GetApi.kt

```
@GET("v2/top-headlines?country=us")
suspend fun getNews(
    @Query("apiKey") apikey: String
):Response<List<NewsData>>
```

ApiClient.kt

```
private val retrofit2 by lazy {
    Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(NEWS_BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
}

val newsApi: GetApi by lazy {
    retrofit2.create(GetApi::class.java)
}
```

Repository.kt

```
suspend fun getNews(apiKey: String):Response<List<NewsData>> {
    return ApiClient.newsApi.getNews(apiKey)
}
```

ArticleViewModel.kt

```
class ArticleActivityViewModel(private val repository: Repository): ViewModel() {
val newsResponse: MutableLiveData<Response<List<NewsData>>> = MutableLiveData()

fun getNews(apiKey: String){
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val n = repository.getNews(apiKey)
        newsResponse.value = n
    }
  }
 }
```

ArticleActivity.kt

```
viewModel.getNews(NEWS_APP_ID)
    viewModel.newsResponse.observe(this, Observer { response ->
        if (response.isSuccessful){
            articleAdapter.setData(response)
        }else{
            Log.d("Response", response.errorBody().toString())
        }
    })
```

ArticleAdapter.kt

```
class ArticleAdapter (private val onItemClickListener: OnItemClickListener): RecyclerView.Adapter<ArticleAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
private var articleList = emptyList<NewsData>()
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.article_row, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(view)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.itemView.article_headline.text = articleList[position].articles[position].title
    holder.itemView.article_author.text = articleList[position].articles[position].author
    holder.itemView.article_date.text = articleList[position].articles[position].publishedAt
    Glide.with(holder.itemView.context).load(articleList[position].articles[position].urlToImage).into(holder.itemView.article_image)

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        onItemClickListener.onClick(articleList[position],position)
    }

}
override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return articleList.size
}

fun setData(newList: List<NewsData>) {
    notifyDataSetChanged()
    articleList = newList
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
}
```

NewsData.kt

```
data class NewsData(
@SerializedName("articles")
val articles: List<Article>,
@SerializedName("status")
val status: String,
@SerializedName("totalResults")
val totalResults: Int
)
```

Article.kt

```
data class Article(
@SerializedName("author")
val author: String,
@SerializedName("content")
val content: String,
@SerializedName("description")
val description: String,
@SerializedName("publishedAt")
val publishedAt: String,
@SerializedName("source")
val source: Source,
@SerializedName("title")
val title: String,
@SerializedName("url")
val url: String,
@SerializedName("urlToImage")
val urlToImage: String
)
```

Source.kt

```
data class Source(
@SerializedName("id")
val id: String,
@SerializedName("name")
val name: String
)
```

I can retrieve data from the server, but can't show it in recyclerview
Logcat result
[image]

How can show this data in recyclerview?

Comment: fun setData(newList: List<NewsData>) {
   
    articleList = newList
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

Comment: You are not sending List<NewsData> to setData, instead you are sending Response<List<NewsData>>, whatever the Response class is, send the value inside it not itself.

Comment: Also you have misconvention, in GetApi it is Response<List<NewsData>> whereas it is Response<NewsData> in repository, fix the return types.

Comment: I already update my question code's,but i can't show list in recyclerview bkz it's retuen response

Comment: make sure you're successfully retrieve the data.

Comment: Yes,it's retrieve data but can't show in recyclerview bkz Type mismatch

Comment: guys plz help me

Answer (score 0):

- You are not sending List to setData, instead, you are sending Response<List>, whatever the Response class is, send the value inside it not itself.
- In GetApi it is Response<List> whereas it is Response in repository, fix the return types

Change it to

```
@GET("v2/top-headlines?country=us")
suspend fun getNews(
    @Query("apiKey") apikey: String
):Response<List<NewsData>>
```

instead of

```
@GET("v2/top-headlines?country=us")
suspend fun getNews(
    @Query("apiKey") apikey: String
):Response<NewsData>
```

Comment: I tried answer but now it's show another problem,the error is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: I will update my code for your suggestion

Comment: please provide the data class of NewsData

Answer (score 0):

As stated you are not sending list instead, you are sending Response. Change the return type from Response<List< NewData >> to List< NewData >

Like this:

```
    @GET("v2/top-headlines?country=us")
    suspend fun getNews(@Query("apiKey") apikey: String):List<NewsData>
```